# Coerce an XTS object to TS for stock daily returns

Tags: r, time-series, xts

i'm scratching my head a lot of hours for this problem. 
I've a `xts` object with stock return, but i need to coerce this object to `ts` .
Below there is an example.

```
date_vec <- as.Date(c("2010-01-05", "2010-01-06","2010-01-07", 
                  "2010-01-08", "2010-01-11", "2010-01-12", 
                  "2010-01-13"))

ret_vec <- rnorm(7)

ret_xts <- xts(ret_vec, order.by = date_vec)
```

As you can see, date are "discontinous" and when i try to force this to `ts` something goes wrong.
Thank you everyone for helping and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use quantmod's function `dailyReturn` (or `periodReturn`). That works with xts objects.

Comment: `ts` is normally not used for daily data.